# Why does React state return undefined but page still loads from state OK?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, state

I am attempting to develop a React app which makes a call to a database to load a set of pages to a board to build a drag and drop decision tree.
I am only just starting out with React, so keen to hear about anything I'm doing wrong here.

Using 'useEffect' the pageTree function will load the pages up on the first load and on every refresh, however the pages state returns with an empty array instead of the current pages.
Strangely enough the pages all show up on the board with the pages.map function which works on the pages state... (which returns as empty on console.log...)

If I add a page to the array it saves the change to the database, but then will only show the new page on the board. You will then have to refresh to see the new set of pages (including the added page).

Calls to add or delete a page are called by the layout menu buttons in the parent component.

[Console after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkTQY.png)

Additionally, if I move a page, the state will console OK:

[Page state in console after moving a page. DB call and state update works OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9ytX.png)

```
function PageTree({AddNewPageFunc}) {
  const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);
  const movePage = useCallback((droppedPage) => {
  const updatedPages = pages.map(page => droppedPage._id == page._id ? droppedPage : page);
  setPages(updatedPages);
    }, [pages]);

  const [{isOver}, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: ItemTypes.PAGECARD,
        drop(page, monitor) {
            const delta = monitor.getDifferenceFromInitialOffset();
            let x = Math.round(page.x + delta.x);
            let y = Math.round(page.y + delta.y);
            page.x = x;
            page.y = y;
            movePage(page);
            setNewPagePosition(page);
            return undefined;
        },
    }), [movePage]);

    const setNewPagePosition = async (pageDetails) => {
        console.log("function called to update page position");
        Api.withToken().post('/pageupdate/'+pageDetails._id,
            pageDetails
        ).then(function (response) {
            console.log("moved page: ",response.data)
        }).catch(function (error) {
          //console.log(error);
        });
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
      AddNewPageFunc.current = AddNewPage
    }, [])

    const AddNewPage = useCallback(() => {
      console.log("calling add new page function")
      console.log("the pages before the API call are ",pages)
      Api.withToken().post('/addblankpage/'
        ).then(function (response) {
          console.log("produced: ",response.data);
          setPages(pages.concat(response.data))
          console.log("the pages after updating state are: ",pages)
      }).catch(function (error) {
        //console.log(error);
      });
    }, [pages]);

    const handleDelete = async (id) => {
        Api.withToken().post('/deletepages/'+id
        ).then(function (response) {
            let index = pages.findIndex(function(item){
              return item.id === response.data._id;
            });
            const PageRemoved = pages.splice(index, 1);
            setPages(PageRemoved);
        }).catch(function (error) {
          //console.log(error);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      Api.withToken().get('/pages/')
      .then(res => {
        setPages(res.data);
        console.log('res data ',res.data);
        console.log('pages ',pages);
      })
    }, []);

  return (
      <div ref={drop} style={styles}>
          {pages.map((page) => (<PageCard page={page} id={page._id} key={page._id} handleDelete={() => handleDelete(page._id)} handleMaximise={() => handleMaximise(page)} handleCopy={() => handleCopy(page)}/>))}
      </div>
      )
}

export default PageTree;
```

Comment: If you are trying to console immediately after setting the state, it will not show the updated value. add `pages` in the dependency array in useEffect, whenever the pages got updated, the component will render.

Comment: I have tried to add pages to the dependency array, but it causes an infinite loop, as useEffect occurs during every change to pages (which occurs on load). I've tried adding a second useEffect to monitor for changes in pages.length, but may have done that incorrectly...

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I was looking at the wrong useEffect, if I add a pages callback for the AddNewPage useEffect then it fixes the issue with adding a new page. It was definitely a callback issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Danielprabhakaran pointed out, the issue was the callback in React.useEffect. On adding a new page it needed to send the updated page state back to the parent component.
Using console.log on a state after an API call seems to be fraught, even if using .then(console.log(state)

```
function PageTree({AddNewPageFunc}) {
  const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);
  const movePage = useCallback((droppedPage) => {
  const updatedPages = pages.map(page => droppedPage._id == page._id ? droppedPage : page);
  console.log("updated pages ",updatedPages);
  setPages(updatedPages);
  console.log("set pages ",pages);
    }, [pages]);

  const [{isOver}, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: ItemTypes.PAGECARD,
        drop(page, monitor) {
            const delta = monitor.getDifferenceFromInitialOffset();
            let x = Math.round(page.x + delta.x);
            let y = Math.round(page.y + delta.y);
            page.x = x;
            page.y = y;
            movePage(page);
            setNewPagePosition(page);
            return undefined;
        },
    }), [movePage]);

    const setNewPagePosition = async (pageDetails) => {
        console.log("function called to update page position");
        Api.withToken().post('/pageupdate/'+pageDetails._id,
            pageDetails
        ).then(function (response) {
            console.log("?worked ",response)
        }).catch(function (error) {
          //console.log(error);
        });
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
      AddNewPageFunc.current = AddNewPage
    }, [pages])

    const AddNewPage = useCallback(() => {
      console.log("calling add new page function")
      console.log("the pages before the API call are ",pages)
      Api.withToken().post('/addblankpage/'
        ).then(function (response) {
          console.log("produced: ",response.data);
          setPages(pages.concat(response.data))
          console.log("the pages after updating state are: ",pages)
      }).catch(function (error) {
        //console.log(error);
      });
    }, [pages]);

    const handleDeletedCallback = (deletedIndex) => {
      console.log("delete callback fired")
      setPages(pages.splice(deletedIndex, 1));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      Api.withToken().get('/pages/') //can add in a prop to return only a given tree once the app gets bigger
      .then(res => {
        setPages(res.data);
        console.log('res data ',res.data);
        console.log('pages ',pages);
      })
    }, []);

  return (
      <div ref={drop} style={styles}>
          {pages.map((page, index) => (<PageCard page={page} id={page._id} key={page._id} index={index} deleteCallback={handleDeletedCallback} handleMaximise={() => handleMaximise(page)} handleCopy={() => handleCopy(page)}/>))}
      </div>
      )
}

export default PageTree;
```